# Target an opened outlook message with an attachment

Tags: outlook

I am trying to target an open outlook message with an attachment. How can this be done? Do I use the inspector property? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\myfile.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks,but that only works if the item in question was the last item in focus.
If you have multiple open emails, it doesn't enumerate through the
collection.

Comment: Ok then, instead of using Application.ActiveInspector, enumerate through the Application.Inspectors collection.